# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - store email on Custom object not contact

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've just started learning marketing cloud. I would like to know if it's possible ( using apex) to add sync the analytics to a custom object and not the contact the email was sent to.
I have a custom object Form__c that will have a lookup field to a contact. I would prefer to store the information on the correspondence on the Form object.

The form will belong to an account (an actor) but the contact's email will belong to another (his representative). There will be multiple forms referencing the same contact.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to configure where the analytics are stored for Marketing Cloud sends when using the Marketing Cloud Connector.  It would be possible to leverage API calls into the Marketing Cloud from Apex to pull the data in such that it could be written to the custom object of your choice.  The standard tracking data sync could then be turned off if this custom process was implemented so that it wouldn't associate data to the Contact record.